# convert list of tuples into numpy array with named columns (genfromtxt for list of tuples)

Tags: python, numpy

So up until now i was reading CSV into numpy array

Sample line:

```
20041207,7.04,7.18,6.88,7.10,25981485
```

The code:

```
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.dates as dt


def mkdate(text):
    return dt.date2num(datetime.datetime.strptime(text, '%Y%m%d'))


np.genfromtxt(
    filename,
    delimiter=',',
    skip_header=1,
    usecols=[1, 2, 5, 3, 4, 6],
    names=('date', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low', 'volume'),
    converters={'date': mkdate},
    dtype=(
        np.float64,
        np.float64,
        np.float64,
        np.float64,
        np.float64,
        np.int64
    )
)
```

Now i must **switch to database**. After getting the relevant values out of database it looks like this (a **list of tuples**):

```
[(datetime.datetime(2004, 12, 7, 0, 0), Decimal('7.04000'), Decimal('7.10000'), Decimal('7.18000'), Decimal('6.88000'), 25981485L), (and so on), ... ]
```

**Now i need to convert in into the same numpy array as before, what i imagine it would be like**:

```
def mkdate(date):
    return dt.date2num(date)

np.somefunction(
    list_of_tuples,
    names=('date', 'open', 'close', 'high', 'low', 'volume'),
    converters={
        'date': mkdate,
        'open': float,
        'close': float,
        'high': float,
        'low': float,
        'volume': int,
    },
    dtype=(
        np.float64,
        np.float64,
        np.float64,
        np.float64,
        np.float64,
        np.int64
    )
)
```

**So to summerize: I need to convert list of tuples into numpy array with named columns.**

Comment: Aside: if you're working with OHLC data, then [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org) is going to be much easier to work with than bare `numpy`.

Answer (score 0):

If `np.readtxt()` is not feasible, maybe it is sufficient for you to have dict with numpy's 1D arrays:

```
tofloat = lambda w: float(w)  # must be function not type
converters={
    'date': mkdate,
    'open': tofloat,
    'close': tofloat,
    'high': tofloat,
    'low': tofloat,
    'volume': lambda w: int(w),
}
# dict with 1D lists per column: 
dd = dict([(k,[]) for k in converters.keys()])  
with open(fname, 'r') as f:
    for l in f:  # read line
       ww = l.split(',') # split line into strings
       for w,k in zip(ww,dd.keys()):  # iterate over strings and column names
           f = converters[k]
           dd[k].append(f(w)) # append to proper dict-entry list
# convert to dict with numpy arrays:
dd_a = dict([(k,np.asarray(v)) for k,v in dd.items()])
```

Comment: If nothing better comes up i will have to use this approach. But it is far from ideal because i use the former array both like array[index]['column_name'] and array['column_name'][index] depending what i need it for. So rewriting significant portions of code will be necessary. But thank you nonetheless as it is a feasible approach.

Comment: You can actually write ``dd_a['column_name'][index]``. If you do not want to change the code, you could write a small wrapper class, where you overload the ``[]``-operator with ``__getitem__()`` to provide the access methods you need.